# Assigning Types Issues in Typescript + React

Tags: reactjs, string, typescript

In my code I currently have a string of type `Data`. I want this string to be appended to the `myContent` array of strings. However, typescript is giving me errors that I can't assign or push my `Data` type into the `myContent`, since `myContent` could be of type `Content[]`.

Is there a workaround to be able to append this string?

Currently, this is where I define my types.

```
export type Data = Content | Content[]

export type Content = 
|string
|otherData
|questionData

//I want a string array in the end
var myContent: Content[] = [];
//Initialize a string
var stringOne = "testString1";
//This works!
myContent.push(stringOne);
```

Comment: It's the opposite. The problem is that your `Data` variable *could* hold `Content[]` and you cannot assign that to `Content`. When you try to add it to an array of `Content` then you might be trying to add an array there, yet `Content` cannot contain an array of itself.

Comment: I'm not trying to add an array. In my code, I happen to have a string which is of type Data, which is why I can't append it to 'myContent

Comment: But the compiler doesn't *know* what the variable actually holds. It's of type `Data` and then *that* type is just an alias to `Content | Content[]`. So, *according to the types you've described*, the variable could hold `Content[]`. Remember that the type check is done at compile time, the compiler doesn't do inferences for what the variable would actually hold at runtime. Not without type guards. Or you can directly bypass that with a type assertion. In your case if the variable holds a string, so, I don't know why you don't just type it as `Content`. Or even `string`.

Comment: How would you cast to a string with Typescript? I thought Typescript didn't allow explicit casting?

Comment: What about changing it to `export type Content =  string | Content[] | your other types`?